# Further differentiation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The question tells us that the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ satisfy $dx/dt=-x^2y$ and $dy/dt= -xy^2$ when $t=0$, $x=1$, and $y=2$. I have already worked out that $dy/dx= (xy^2)/(x^2y)$ and that $y=2x$. Now given that $dx/dt=-2x^3$ deduce a formula for $x$ as a function of $t$.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you know how to solve the differential equation $x'(t) = -2x^3, x(0) = 1$?

Comment: No I don't think so

Comment: Does "separable differential equation" sound familiar: you can write $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -2x^3$, leading to $\dfrac{dx}{-2 x^3} = dt$, and then you can integrate (see charlotte's solution below)

Comment: Well I probably do I just can't think of how to do it

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense!! Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. If one of the answers below solves your problem, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for a full explanation

Comment: And you will get points yourself for accepting an answer, @RachelBinnie Everyone wins!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You just have to separate the variables -

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x^3$$
$$-\frac{dx}{2x^3}=dt$$
$$-\int\frac{dx}{2x^3}= t+C$$
$$\frac{1}{4x^2}=t+C$$
$$x=\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+C}}$$

$$1 = \pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{C}}$$

Assuming $C\in\mathbb{R}$, this means $C=\frac{1}{4}$ and only the positive solution is admitted. Then
$$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4t+1}}$$